# A tables title bar with inner elements

Tags: css, html

I am making a title bar for a table. It has to be contained inside a table row just because the rest of the page has been designed for a table (which I cannot change at this stage).

What I want to do is create a block inside the table row that contains some text, a few buttons (as images) and some input boxes and a dropdown selection option.

I've been playing round with divs and floating them which works well enough but the inputs and image buttons are not aligning nicely so I played with using spans instead which works kinda nicer but still not aligning as I need it to. It all needs to fit inside the blue bar and the small white gap between the the blue bar and the grey strip shouldn't be there...

Heres what it looks like at the moment... 
[image]

Here is my code with the block using divs and its essentially the same with spans

```
<td colspan='8'> <-- this is the start of the table cell that i have to work inside
<div style="width: 100%; ">

    <div class="tableHeadRow" style="float: left; background-color: #002b59; padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px; width: 678px;">
        <form method='post' name='tranLookup'>

            <input type='hidden' name='dates' value='range' />
            <input type='hidden' name='op' value='viewTransactions' />

            <span style="margin-right: 10px; color: #ffffff; ">Transaction History</span>

            <div class="printerButtonWrapper flow" style="margin-right: 10px; display: inline-block;">
                <a id="printButton" href="#toPrint">
                    <img src="images/accounts.png" alt="Printer View" class="clip printerButton" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div style="margin-right: 10px; display: inline-block;">
                <input placeholder="From date: " type='text' id='fromDate' name='fromDate' class="textbox calText" style='width: 80px;' value="startDate">
                <span style="color: #ffffff">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
                <input placeholder="To date: " type='text' id='toDate' name='toDate' class="textbox calText" style='width: 80px;' value="endDate">
            </div>

            <div style="margin-right: 10px;  display: inline-block; ">
                <span style="color: #ffffff;">Transactions per page:</span>
                <select name='qty' id="transactionQuantity">
                    <option value='10'>10</option>
                    <option value='25' selected="selected">25</option>
                    <option value='50'>50</option>
                    <option value='100'>100</option>
                    <option value='200'>200</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="goWrapper flow" style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; ">
                <a onclick='document.tranLookup.submit();'><img src='images/accounts.png' alt='Go' class='clip go' /></a>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

    <div class="blueCornerWrapper flow" style="float: right; display: inline-block; ">
        <img src='images/common.png' alt='' class='clip blueCorner' />
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;" ></div>

</div></td> <-- heres the end of the table cell
```

Frustratingly I had this all sorted once but I didn't commit code and I lost it all so now I am trying to get it back to its nice aligned state unfortunately it was a couple months ago now and I cant remember what I did...

Does anyone have some awesome mad skills to help me line these up nicely?

Answer (score 2):

Let's get started by cleaning up your code.

Let's have a fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/a3985/

Have a play with this. I gave the td a transactionSelection ID. There is no need for a div, the form will do. I have removed the img tags leaving just the links. You should have the images placed in your css like this for example:

```
#transactionSelection #goSubmit { background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat; }
```

HTML

```
<td colspan='8' id="transactionSelection">



    <form method='post' name='tranLookup'>
        <legend>Transaction History</legend>

        <input type='hidden' name='dates' value='range' />
        <input type='hidden' name='op' value='viewTransactions' />




            <a  href="#toPrint" id="printButton"></a>


            <input placeholder="From date: " type='text' id='fromDate' name='fromDate' class="textbox calText" style='width: 80px;' value="startDate">
            <input placeholder="To date: " type='text' id='toDate' name='toDate' class="textbox calText" style='width: 80px;' value="endDate">



            <label for="transactionQuantity">Transactions per page:</label>
            <select name='qty' id="transactionQuantity">
                <option value='10'>10</option>
                <option value='25' selected="selected">25</option>
                <option value='50'>50</option>
                <option value='100'>100</option>
                <option value='200'>200</option>
            </select>



            <button onclick='document.tranLookup.submit();' id="goSubmit">Submit</button>


    </form>
```

CSS - Place this in an external sheet if possible or in your head. Because you are dealing with legacy code I would recommend all css being restricted to #transactionSelection which is the id of the td.

```
#transactionSelection  legend, #transactionSelection label, #transactionSelection     select { margin: 2px 0 0; float: left; }
#transactionSelection input { float: left; margin: 2px 10px; }
#transactionSelection label { margin-right: 10px; }

#transactionSelection #printButton { display: block; float: left; height: 20px; width: 50px;  padding: 2px; margin: 0 20px; background: #F00; }
#transactionSelection #goSubmit { display: block; float: left; height: 20px; width: 50px;  padding: 2px; margin: 3px 20px; background: #F00; border: none; float: left; }
```

This is a good starting point if you would really like to clean this up.

Sam

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle. Have a play. Also, your background can be applied to the td.

Answer (score 0):

Before I reveal a solution, I just want to say that it would make things way easier for you(and everyone else) if you wrote your css on a separate sheet. Also, it's best not to use tables anymore, but you probably already knew that ;)

What I did was I used `display:inline-block;` for the child elements, so that they are treated as text, and I used `text-align:center;` for the parent `div`. And to fix your alignment issues, I used `vertical-align:middle;`. I then gave the `div` with the blue background a greater `height` and now it looks good.

[See for yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/64Uq5/)***<----THIS IS THE FIDDLE***

```
.tableHeadRow{
text-align:center;
height:30px;
}
span,.printerButtonWrapper,#printButton,.clip printButton,input .textbox calText,select   #transactionQuantity,img {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I agree that it would be easier if my css was on its separate style sheet, while I was playing round with the div and span tags I found it easier to leave it inline...

Unfortunately I cant change the height, there is an image being used for the rounded edge on the right hand side if you have a look at the image I attached there is a small cut off rounded bit, this is the blue corner section in my code...

'text-align: center' would center my text horizontally not vertically which is what I'm having issues with. 

For some reason the 'vertical-align: middle' doesn't align everything up correct

Comment: Did you take a look at my fiddle? Everything is aligned, including the images.

Comment: Notice that I used `display:inline-block;` on **all** elements inside `.tableHeadRow`.